# CustomEvent, событие которое следит за содержимым блока

Tags: javascript

У меня есть блок: `<div class="dataBlock"></div>`.

Как создать событие, которое будет срабатывать всегда, когда что-то меняется внутри этого блока (при этом мы не можем добавлять какие-либо `callback` в скрипт который непосредственно меняет содержимое `.dataBlock`)?

Нужно сделать что-то вроде `.addEventListener("myEvent", ...)` и, когда что-то изменилось, - вывести какой-нибудь `alert()`.

Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По [ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), которую указал предыдущий отвечающий можно найти пример как [добавить эвенте для DOM елемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  // ...
}, false);
```

Список всех mutailevent так же можно найти по ссылке выше, либо поискать их в [официальной документации](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents):

- DOMAttrModified
- DOMAttributeNameChanged
- DOMCharacterDataModified
- DOMElementNameChanged
- DOMNodeInserted
- DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument
- DOMNodeRemoved
- DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument
- DOMSubtreeModified

Так же будет полезно узнать какие эвенты (не) поддерживаются разными браузерами, это можно найти по ссылке [тут](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents).

Comment: Mutation event уже Deprecated.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а что тогда использовать заместо листнера об изменении ДОМ?

Comment: @VostokSisters [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Лучше по производительности и меньше возни с вычислением изменений в дереве DOM.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, уже накопал на эту тему и также пришел к  MutationObserver, спасибо)

Comment: @VostokSisters, думаю имеет смысл написать развернутый ответ про MutationObserver ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я уже задал свой [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621031/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/621053#621053)  про такое же примерно, там дополню своим кодом с использованием этого