# Проверять наличие скролла в реальном времени

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция для определения, есть скролл или нет (это то, что найдено по поиску в СО, если знаете функцию получше - приложите её к ответу, пожалуйста, или в комменты):

```
function get_scroll(a) {
  var d = document,
      b = d.body,
      e = d.documentElement,
      c = "client" + a;
      a = "scroll" + a;
  return /CSS/.test(d.compatMode)? (e[c]< e[a]) : (b[c]< b[a])
};
```

Использование:

```
get_scroll('Width') – есть ли горизонтальный скролл
get_scroll('Height') – есть ли вертикальный скролл
```

И хотелось бы узнать, как на js модернизировать его, чтобы отслеживать в реальном времени наличие скролла у body, ну и предпринимать какие-то действия. Например, инжектить в параграф текст о том, есть он или нет.

Вопрос больше, наверно, о отслеживании в реальном времени свойств элемента, но часто спрашивают вопрос "а для чего такая реализация нужна", так что вот, сразу решил сказать первопричину.

Comment: Что значит "в реальном времени"? Клиентский js, что в нереальном времени каком-то выполняется?

Comment: @Sublihim, если я напишу в теге `<script>` в самом-самом низу тега `body` такой код, как в вопросе, и ещё  с вызовом `console.log(get_scroll('Width'))` для вызова,  он будет циклично выполняться до скончания веков? Неправда же.

Comment: @VostokSisters, добавьте в функцию рекурсию и будет бесконечно вызываться

Comment: @MasterAlex, ну естественно можно, но не думаю, что это хороший подход для производительности...

Comment: @VostokSisters, второй вариант это через `setInterval`

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать MutationObserver. Ведь изменение контента приведет к изменению высоты клиента. Соответственно повесьте его на body

Comment: Хотя, конечно, при изменении, к примеру, только высоты DIV, который приведет к появлению scroll - MutationObserver наверно не поможет

Comment: @MasterAlex, нет, никаких поддергиваний не должно быть. 50 миллисекунд будут заметны глазу. А выставить минимальное количество, всё равно что интервала бы и не было. Я не думаю, что рекурсия нормальное решение...

Comment: @Sublihim, сейчас попробую погуглить, посмотреть, спасибо за наводку

Comment: @VostokSisters посмотрите еще Mutation событие DOMAttrModified. Только учтите, что не все браузеры поддерживают MutationObserver

Comment: @Sublihim, MDN говорит, что это нежелательная фича и что убрана из веб-стандартов. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: @VostokSisters тогда, кроме как проверка через отрезки времени, через setInterval, врядли еще что-то поможет :)

Comment: @Sublihim, ну хотя... http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Comment: В FF и Хроме есть события, на которые можно подписаться (разные, т. к. в стандарте ничего такого нет). Кроссбраузерно и по стандарту (надеюсь) знаю как определить увеличение высоты, но не уменьшение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну вот я сделал полностью работающую [штуку](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/LxeXYj?editors=0011), которая говорит, есть ли скролл у элемента или у боди, или нет (учитываются даже заданные `overflow: scroll`). Разве нельзя следить за этими свойствами через мутации, это ведь обычные элементы страницы? Мне кажется можно, я у же на полпути к реализации.

Comment: @VostokSisters, а если я в css на `:hover` изменение высоты какой-нибудь поставлю, разве это отследится? Или css-анимации? А то ведь изменения не всегдя связаны с изменением контента. Ах да, а если я размер окна браузера поменяю (хотя на это как раз можно подписаться)? Или использую flex, когда изменения в параллельном поддереве порождают появление скролла у тебя? Вариантов тьма, вообще-то.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в ответе я дал ссылку, в ответе на другой вопрос который приводятся много свойств для настройки, за чем следить. Ну честно говоря, я без понятия, будет ли отслеживаться настолько детально :D Но вот тьму ты в меня посеял, потому что изменение размера экрана мне нужно отслеживать... Не знаю. Сделаю - посмотрю)

Comment: @Qwertiy, единственное что я протестил, это вставка-удаление дочерних элементов, изменение аттрибутов (в том числе уже заданых). Появление псевдоэлементов у дочерних элементов (они при ховере появляются как раз таки, с транзишином). Посмотрим короче...

Answer (score 1):

Я не нашел всё-таки решения, чтобы следить за появлением и исчезновением курсора в реальном времени. Во всяком случае прямого решения нет (отбрасывая вариант с рекурсивной функцией проверки через интервал).
Можно лишь ограничиться тем, чтобы наблюдать за изменениями, которые могут произойти, и в следствии чего они повлияют на появление скролла на странице. Мы эти действия ловим (или предусматриваем в простых случаях), и реагируем функцией проверки, которая что-то делает в связи с этим, что вам нужно. Реализация - сугубо пользовательская и вряд ли найдется модульное решение хоть когда-нибудь в виде библиотечки.
Для просмотра событий, можно "вешать" события методом `.addEventListner`, а для таких сложных, как добавление в дом (или удаление), присуждение элементу класса (и какого класса), можно отслеживать `MutationObserver`. Последнее - сложная штука, которая требует для Firefox оптимизации и будьте готовы (если с этим не работали раньше) потратить солидное время на понимание, если действительно не собираетесь всего лишь следить за добавлением класса элементу.
В итоге я использовал связку: следить за ресайзом окна, а также `MutationObserver` для более сложных штук, которые могут произойти с элементами, и что может повлиять на появление скролла. Можете потестить, что у меня получилось, если хочется, [тут](https://vostoksisters.github.io/gallery/somethingserious/). При загрузке нет скролла, после появлении изображений ничего не слетает. При клике на картинку, открывается модальное окно, если изменить высоту, появится скролл, но картинка в модальном окне не уедет влево, и много других мелочей я предусмотрел. Но кросс-проектного решения не думаю, что смогу описать, поэтому кота никакого не привожу.
Ответ на вопрос, в принципе, кончается, но если интересно, то пример: реализация контроля скролла во ВКонтакте. Если откроете страницу на этом сайте без наличия скролла (например, закладки, они должны быть не особо забиты), и начнете ресайзить окно по высоте, то скролл будет появляться и исчезать (по ресайзу вниз), но сама страница не будет сдвигаться влево (по добавлению скролла) или вправо (при его отсутствии).
Во ВКонтакте это реализовано топорно, очень. Если залезть в просмоторщик элементов, то увидим у `body` функцию-обработчик 'onBodyResize()', которая, по всей видимости, всю логику осуществляет. Если полазить и понаходить div-обёртки сайта, в том числе и модального окна (где контроль скролла также предусмотрен), то увидим, что у них при ресайзе окна всегда инлайнятся новые параметры стилей, такие как высота и ширина. То есть это происходит перерасчет стилей всегда, что весьма затратно, но вроде как работа сайта успешна в плане производительности, но тоже решение.

Comment: Ответ типа "Есть ответ тут: ссылка" - ответ-ссылка, что тут запрещено.

Comment: @Other, ну так пометь как дубликат, в чем проблема.

Comment: @Other, или хочешь чтобы я скопировал ответ из другого вопроса? Потому что ответ тот же самый объективно.

Comment: Но это не вопрос-дубликат. Копирование хотя бы сути чужого ответа - уже что-то.

Comment: @Other, то есть если скопирую текст с ответа (заместо приведенной ссылки с моими собственными пояснениями), то меня плюсами засыпят, а если даю ссылку на топик, ответ которого ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ можно решить мою проблему, это осуждается? Слушай, я уже второй раз встречаю, что я что-то не по правилам делаю. Можно ли тут вообще как-нибудь следовать логике, а не сухим правилам?

Comment: @Other, я тут тревогу на ответ кидал, где решением совершенно не был тот ответ с кучей плюсов и галочкой, тревогу сняли. Но ответ если просто в консоль вбить, он не работает, это не я тупой, 100% ответ был косячный. И тревогу отклонили. Не очень верится в наличие правоты тут на портале.

Comment: Не стоит кипятится. Есть простое правило: ответы-ссылки - это нехорошо, пусть даже на этот же сайт ведут.

Comment: Ответ вполне мог быть верным, но не в плане "Всё в чистом виде сделал для Вас, босс",  а "Вот абстрактный пример".

Comment: @Other, я не буду копипастить, потому что это не ответ на мой вопрос, если ты не понял, я разъясняю это прямо снизу ссылки (та большая куча текста, если не видел). Ссылки приводить можно. Она - не ответ. Можно использовать в качестве отправной точки. Галку себе не повесил, потому что ответ на вопрос это не дает. Чем ещё не довольно твое честолюбивое сердце? :D Труби тревогу тогда, я менять не буду ничего.

Comment: Если по ссылке есть ответ - скопируйте хотя бы суть сюда. Если по ссылке ответа нет, только пояснения/фоточки_с_котиками - Ваш ответ -- не ответ вовсе, а комментарий/обновление_вопроса и его нужно удалить.

Comment: @Other, ответа нет (и быть не может в текущем моменте времени, как я понял), есть частичное решение, которое я привел. Подходит ли оно под стандарты сообщества - не подходит под стандарты, ты знаешь куда стучать и чего добиваться. Я считаю это не ответом на мой вопрос, но решением моей проблемы, о чём я написал в дополненном варианте. Тупиковые перепалки я не веду.

Comment: Ваше право. Но с таким отношением Вы закончите как-то так: Будете нарушать нормы сообщества, пинать тех, кто пытается Вам помочь, потом придёт дядя с банхаммером и Вы побежите на мету/хабр плакаться -- какие тут злые и несправедливые люди.

Comment: @Other человек с "банхаммером" - тоже человек, которого тоже может бесить всякое, и тогда правила отходят очень и очень, и очень далеко, а "плакаться", как ты говоришь, тому же самому  человеку не имеет смысла совершенно.  Я не верю в правила на форумах, как и в то, что ты сейчас пытаешься мне помочь, а не провоцировать.

Comment: Хотел бы провоцировать, сказал бы что думаю о Вашем упрямстве и враждебном настрое. Но я лишь пытаюсь Вас донести местный устав. Верите ли Вы в правила или нет - сообщество не даст их нарушать. Модераторы могут ошибаться, они, как Вы метко подметили, тоже люди (хотя некоторые утки, но не суть), но в целом решает сообщество, которое коллективом правильно решает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52959/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and-other).